# Trying to extract quotes from a string with unbalanced quotes

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to extract quotes from a string. My code works except for cases where the initial quotation is repeated (certain strings have this).

Example:

```
"I was walking down the street. I heard a loud noise. 
I wonder what it was?

"I got scared and kept walking."
```

In cases like this my code starts by identifying the first `"` and begins returning the words after, but then it runs into the second (middle) `"` and restarts, thus only returning the last line. How can I make my code return the entire quoted phrase (in this case it is everything)?

Here is my code:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as txt:
    reader = txt.read()
    x = re.findall(r'"([^"]+)"', reader, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I don't see how you can solve this. If the quotes aren't properly matched, how are you supposed to know which ones start new quotations?

Comment: Your code returns everything *except* the last line, not the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the quotes in the matched pattern, make them lookarounds.

```
x = re.findall(r'(?<=")([^\s"][^"]*)(?=")', reader, re.DOTALL)
```

Then it will return each quoted string, since they no longer overlap. The result is

```
['I was walking down the street. I heard a loud noise. \nI wonder what it was?\n\n', 
 'I got scared and kept walking.']
```

Comment: The text I am checking uses “ and ” (curly quotes) instead of straight quote ("). It works for the straight quotes but not the curly ones. I am not sure why as this code should find the first curly quote and then ignore any others until it reaches the closing curly quote?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x? It requires the `re.UNICODE` flag to match Unicode characters.

Comment: I am using 3.11. I was able to replace all instances of curly quotes with straight quotes (not the best code but it works for the meanwhile) and it does not work. It returns the words after the quotations as well.

Comment: I don't know why. I tested the above code, and that was the actual output.

Comment: Try testing this please:  Hello my name is John. "I was walking down the street. I heard a loud noise. 
I wonder what it was?

"I got scared and kept walking." Then I went to bed. "I had a good night." I woke up in the morning.

Comment: I get `['I was walking down the street. I heard a loud noise. I wonder what it was? ', 'I got scared and kept walking.', ' Then I went to bed. ', 'I had a good night.']` That looks correct.

Comment: The only text after the quotations is `I woke up in the morning.` and it doesn't return that.

Comment: Were you hoping it would leave out `Then I went to bed`? But that's between the quotes after `walking.` and before `I`. Should it prohibit a space at the beginning of the returned string?

Comment: I've changed the regexp so the first character of the capture group can't be a space. Now it returns `['I was walking down the street. I heard a loud noise. I wonder what it was? ', 'I got scared and kept walking.', 'I had a good night.']`

Comment: Yes that was the issue. 'Then I went to bed' is not quoted even though it is between quotation marks. Let me try that. Thanks.